# What is the difference between "for every $x$ there exists a $y$" and "for all $x$ there exists a $y$"?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, uniform-continuity

Is there any difference between them? or are they same?
I was going through the definition of uniform continuity, which uses the term "for every". Can someone explain me the difference between the two terminologies. 
Please try to explain it in the context of uniform continuity definition.
Thanks!

Comment: No difference; see [Universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification).

Comment: Did you mean the difference between “every” and “all” or the difference between “for every $x$ there exists a $y$“ and “for every $y$ there exists an $x$”? I think I may have misunderstood the question when I edited it...

Comment: I meant the difference between for all and for every

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have stated it in your title, the two statements are equivalent.

But you probably wanted something different.

For every $x$ there exists a $y$ means that $y$ depends on $x$ and may as well change with $x$.

For example for every $x$ there exists  a $y$ such that $y=x^2$  (that is a true statement )

On the other hand there exists a $y$ such that for all $x$, $y=x^2$ is false.

Thus you may not switch the different quantifiers around.

Comment: yes, I think I might have framed the question wrongly.

Comment: In the example provided by you for "for all", you have switched the quantifiers ( there exist and for all), which is why it is making "for all" seem different from "for every". Otherwise, both of them actually mean the same and are interchangeably used in the literature.